# Setting up Eclipse to connect to Sourceforge CVS

Tags: eclipse, sourceforge

I am new to SourceForge and CVS in general. Having some difficulties setting up Eclipse to connect to SoureForge CVS.

I have created project on http://testjavaproj.sourceforge.net, enabled(added) CVS option in SourceForge, have SSH/shell privileges.

In Eclipse added CVS repository with the following information
HOST: cvs.sourceforge.net
Repository Path: /cvsroot/Test_Java_project
Connection Type: extssh

update:
I found some info on SourceForge website

`cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@testjavaproj.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/testjavaproj login`
`cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@testjavaproj.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/testjavaproj co -P modulename`

Tried to log-in using:
Host: testjavaproj.cvs.sourceforge.net
Repository Path:/cvsroot/testjavaproj

However, I am still getting the error message:
`Error fetching resource list from repository. Reason: Could not connect to :extssh:differential@testjavaproj.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/testjavaproj: CVS communication error: org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ssh2.CVSSSH2ServerConnection$SSH2IOException: Connection refused: connect`

Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you try to connect?

Comment: I have update the post with error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SourceForge CVS services are down. See Site Status.

Answer (score 0):

Try with host: `testjavaproj.svn.sourceforge.net`
and repository path: `/cvsroot/testjavaproj`